# Automatic growth in two-dimensional arrays

Tags: c, arrays

In the C language, is there a way to automatically grow an array.
For example:

```
int arr [100] [10];
```

If the array is full is it possible to have it "automatically" become larger? Or is that only possible if you're using C++. How would you write this in C?

Comment: C99 and VLA — variable length array — might be appropriate, though it won't copy existing data.  Failing that, dynamic memory allocation via `malloc()` and `realloc()` and friends.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such feature in C: you have to declare the array using pointers, detect the "array is full" condition manually, call `malloc`, make a copy into an extended array, and `free` the original one. Even the variable-length arrays would not work, because they let you set their size only once per the array lifetime.

In C++, you can use `std::vector<std::vector<int> >` instead of a plain array. You still need to detect the "array is full" condition, but the `std::vector<T>` container takes care of all re-allocations and extensions on resizing for you.

Answer (score 1):

"automatic" growth of any array in C is not possible. If you declare an array statically:

```
int arr[10];
```

you have however many memory locations as you indicated. If you want to be able to change it during runtime you need to declare it dynamically using `malloc()` and make it larger using `realloc()`

A quick example for you:

```
int main(void){
    int input, count = 0, length = 2;
    int * arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * length); // array of size 2

    while((input = getchar()) != 'q') //get input from the user
    {
        getchar();                    //get rid of newlines
        arr[count] = input;           
        if(count + 1 == length){      // if our array is running out of space
            arr = realloc(arr, length * length);  // make it twice as big as it was
            length *= length;
        }
        count++;
    }

    for(length = 0; length < count; length++)  // print the contents
        printf("%d\n", arr[length]);

    free(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I have some small doubt

In this program, I understand, but why I enter into the fourth number

Fifth enter "q" program dead

Or that my fourth input "q"

The contents of the display than the previous three

And the program is also dead

Thank you

Comment: 'q', as in Quit, was simply chosen as the termination for this sample program, it was more about demonstrating the realloc function. In this example checking the result of the user input as the exit condition for the while allows us to loop but not have to capture the exit condition in our array